# Postfix: Avoiding backscatter when acting as backup MX with unknown valid recipiants

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm running Postfix 3.1.0, acting as backup MX (i.e. I have `relay_domains` set) for a domain whose valid recipients I cannot practically know. Thus, I would normally be producing backscatter when I accept misdirected messages (usually spam that's not spammy enough to get rejected by Rspamd) for the next-hop domain.

I have set `bounce_service_name = discard` to suppress all bouncing, but this means my own users don't get legitimate bounces.

The only [other relevant question](https://serverfault.com/questions/226560/avoid-creating-backscatter-on-a-postfix-forwarding-server) I could find here suggested it's impossible to selectively suppress bouncing. Given that six years have passed since then, is that still true?

One possible solution, I thought, would be if the bounce service (in `master.cf`) can be configured with `transport_maps`; is that possible?